# Swift: return type when using map on optionals depends on closure

Tags: swift, option-type

```
func times3(number : Int) -> Int {
    return 3 * number
} 

let opt1 : Int? = 5

let mapped = opt1.map(times3)
// mapped is 15

let m = opt1.map({times3(number: $0)})
print(m)
// m is Optional(15)
```

Why is mapped an Int, but m an an Int?
both are using the same function!?

Comment: Sorry Hamish. I used the swift playground app on my iPad. It showed mapped as Int and m as Int? . I didn´t expect the app to show wrong results

Comment: Huh, that's weird – you should [file a bug report with Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com) then in that case :)

Comment: I filed a bug-report (29198279)

Answer (score 1):

What makes you believe that `mapped` has type `Int`? I just tried in the REPL and `mapped` has type `Int?`, as expected.

```
Welcome to Apple Swift version 3.0.1 (swiftlang-800.0.58.6 clang-800.0.42.1). Type :help for assistance.
  1> func times3(number: Int) -> Int {
  2.   return 3 * n
  3. }
  4> let opt1: Int? = 5
opt1: Int? = 5
  5> let mapped = opt1.map(times3)
mapped: Int? = 15
  6> let m = opt1.map({times3(number: $0)})
m: Int? = 15
```

Comment: Gabrielle. I used the swift playground app on my iPad. It showed mapped as Int and m Int?